# Wahoo kickr BLE not finding CSC service

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to make a grade simulator for my bike trainer with arduino like on:
https://www.instructables.com/Open-Bicycle-Grade-Simulator-OpenGradeSIM/

The problem i am facing right now is that i can't seem to find the CSC service in the bluetooth device.

the cycling power service (0x1818) i can find and is working,
But the CSC sercive (0x1816) i can not find.
Even with bluetooth apps on my smartphone i can seem to find the service.
I know it must be broadcasted somehow because the Zwift app finds it somehow.
Does anybody knows how they do it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a dedicated Bluetooth CSC device (https://buy.garmin.com/en-US/US/p/641221) or are you getting the cadence from the Smart Trainer?

The CSC Service (0x1816) is coming from a dedicated cadence or speed sensor and thus, if you do not have one in service/use, then you most certainly would not be able to find it.

If you're looking just for cadence, then it depends on whether your Smart Trainer (Wahoo KICKR) transmits that data. (My own smart trainer - Magene Gravat2 - does not transmit cadence so I have to use my own dedicated unit).

Assuming that you are indeed looking for cadence from your trainer (I highly suspect that your Kickr does transmit cadence). You can obtain the Cadence from the trainer itself.

For ANT+FEC (over BLE - which is what I'm using) the cadence is transmitted from page 25. (you can see the framing of the message in this SO [Sending user weight to Smart Trainer via ANT+FEC over BLE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65860752/14414215))

```
  /// Page 25 (0x19) – Specific Trainer/Stationary Bike Data
  /// Cad 0xFF trainer cannot measure pedaling cadence.
  ///
  /// (note: ANT+FEC over BLUE data is 12 bytes and looks like this )
  /// 0xa4  0x09        0x4f  0x00     0x19 0xc5 0xff 0x49 0x49 0x00 0x30 0x30 0xc1
  /// Data: 0x19  0xc5       0xff    0x49         0x49         0x2C         0x01         0x30  0xc1
  ///       Page  EventCount InsCad  AccumPwrLSB  AccumPwrMSB  InsPowerLSB  InsPowerMSB  Flag  Checksum

  /// Check if Trainer is sending Cadence
  if ( Int(byteArray[6]) != 255) {
    cadence = Int(byteArray[6])
  }
```

[image: ANT+FEC Data Page 25]

Since you're using Bluetooth, I am not sure if you're gonna use the Cycling Power Measurement Service or the FTMS service. In any case, here a screenshot of both the relevant pages in both document..

[image]

I looked an your linked project page and yes, it's interesting and since you have a Kickr, I guess the need for a rotating rear axle is not a concern. AFAIK, that's one main reason why the Kickr Climb is only useful for the Kickr. (EDIT: now I understand what he did!. Genius!)

Skimming thru the project page, I'm curious why you need cadence? Thinking more about it, I think you want Speed and not cadence right?

For Speed, Most trainers also transmit virtual speed on page 16 (ANT+FEC over BLE) but I'm guessing that you're doing it for Zwift? I've not done any comparison between Zwift Virtual Speed and the trainer's reported Virtual speed so I can't comment. If you're using a dedicatad speed/cad sensor, where you gonna put it? So, I'm gonna assume that you're just gonna use the virtual speed (reported) from the trainer. (again, how this differs from the speed in Zwift I have no idea)

have you looked at this https://github.com/vincent290587/Climber and https://www.thisisant.com/forum/viewthread/7106/ ? according to the guy, zwift is indeed sending the slope on page 51 (that's what I do as well for my own app - http://apps.apple.com/us/app/breakaway-indoor-training/id1541280053)

```
if Int(byteArray[4]) == 16 {
  /// FEC speed is in 0.001m/s, telemetry speed is km/h
  /// Int(byteArray[11]) = 52 (0x34) = 110100 (Binary)
  /// 110100
  ///   ||||-> 00 Invalid
  ///   ||___>  1 FE Will transmit Dist
  ///   |____>  0 Real Speed
  /// FEC:[164, 9, 79,  0, 16, 25,  7, 152,  0,  0, 255, 52, 191]
  /// HEX:  a4 09  4f  00  10  19  07   98  00  00   ff  34   bf
  
  /// Instant Speed
  let speed = (Int(byteArray[9]) << 8) + Int(byteArray[8])
  //  let speedkmh = String(format:"%.1f", (Double(speed) * 0.0036))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, i checked the cpm service flags and the trainer is outputing also speed and cadence. the cadence is not necessary but nice to see.

Comment: i checked with zwift and the power and cadence looks the same but the speed is off. i noticed when riding a steady tempo and the same power the speed is changing with the incline in zwift but my readings speed stay the same. i tought it was coming from the erg mode but its the same in normal mode.

Comment: @johnnyvandeputte okay, so you've answer the question I posed which was "how the speed from the trainer differs from the speed that zwift reports". Based on this, my guess is that there is calculation difference between Zwift and the trainer. If Zwift was/is using real life physics then it would/should be using user weight + incline + Gravity + wind + rolling resistance + draft and the like to calculate speed. You can read more here https://www.gribble.org/cycling/power_v_speed.html